# Product Export - Dataflow Profiles takes to 500 error page

Tags: magento-1.8, error, export, dataflow

I'm trying to export products from Magento 1.8.1.0 but when I go to the following location, it just comes with a 500 page error straight away.

> System > Import / Export > Dataflow - Profiles

I checked the logs and it has been narrowed down to this:

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Unserialize_Reader_ArrKey' not found in
>   magento/lib/Unserialize/Reader/Arr.php on line 88

How can I fix this? It looks like a patch might not of been applied properly or something.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on Magento 1.8 something went wrong ...

`Unserialize_Reader_Arr`, `Unserialize_Reader_ArrKey`, `Unserialize_XYZ` were added in Magento 1.9.2.2.

**Edit:**

These files were also part of `SUPEE-6788`. Please check if the patch was applied correctly.

Download: https://magento.com/tech-resources/download

Comment: Thanks. Looks like the IT person who setup the website for us must of messed up when patching. Is there no way to fix this?